# React: Updating Component State with Direct Value Assignment - Any reason not to?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React, and am storing information needed only by my component in the component's state. I am running into a problem with the asynchronous nature of the `this.setState` call.

I have made my way around this by just assigning the state value directly, with `this.state.stateKey = newValue`. See below for a specific short sample case that demonstrates how this.setState does not work for me and the direct assignment does.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Test extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        testVal : "Enter new text here"
    }
}
    runTest = (evt) => {
        // if I run the test with the below line, the value
        // in state is not updated before the console.log
        this.setState({testVal: evt.target.value});

        // if I run the test with the below line, the value
        // in state is loaded before the console.log call,
        // and I do get a print of the new value
        this.state.testVal = evt.target.value;

        console.log("testVal: ", this.state.testVal);
    }

    render = () => {
        return(
        <div>
            Test
            <input
                class="form-control"
                type="text"
                defaultValue={this.state.testVal}
                onBlur={this.runTest}
            />
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My question is there anything wrong with updating state with direct assignment using `this.state.stateKey = newValue`? I see other workarounds, but no mention of this. And it seems so simple that there must be something wrong with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating an immutable clone of state is a good idea because of the way state changes are compared in order to optimise rendering.

In lifecycle methods like shouldComponentUpdate, nextProps are passed in and can be compared to this.props.

If you mutate the state directly, then **nextProps.someprop and this.props.someprop will always be the same** and therefore you might not get the expected behaviour.

The [React doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) also says

> NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

Comment: Ok, I get it. It's about the immutability of state. Thanks. I wonder if I should be storing my values somewhere besides state, because they are temporary values used by multiple functions to draw an image. All the data needed to draw the image is in the backend DB. So, keeping a record of the data I have in the state and how it has changed over time is not important. If you have any suggestions about this, I'm all ears.

Comment: If you are absolutely sure that these values are not changed or if changed, they do not have any sort of affect in the UI, then you can store these values in class variables

Comment: Thanks again. Some preliminary testing of using class variables looks good. Appreciate the help.